# silent installation with install4j

Tags: installation, install4j

I am trying to make some silent installations with install4j, like running other executable programs but the user still can see the gui of these programs. What should I do to hide them?

Answer (score 18):

When running an installer created with install4j add `-q` for [unattended mode](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/helptopics/installers/installerModes.html).

Comment: The question ist not to suppress the UI of the created installer itself, but to suppress the UI of an embedded sub-setup.

That would highly depend onb the other setups or applications, if they have a silent or unattendet option.

Answer (score 0):

use below responce file with the following command.
yEd-3.20.1_with-JRE13_64-bit_setup.exe -q -varfile "response.varfile"

response.varfile:just install the application manually on any one machine, after you can get the response file on the location "C:\Program Files\yWorks\yEd"

Answer (score -4):

I think it is impossible to hide a GUI of another process.

Comment: This answer is dangerously general, also wrong in general, and not helpful in answering this question.